# I'm trying to call the selected class in the class method

Tags: c++, class, oop

So, I am working on a school project and it's all going well except I have to call a function that requires a class as an argument. I need the function in a class method and I was wondering how do you fill in the argument? I will leave a sample code below

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class x
{
public:
    int x = 0;
    void f();
};

void g(x aux)
{
    cout << aux.x << endl;
}

void x::f()
{
    g(); //Here is the problem
}

int main()
{
    x a;
    a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `g(*this);`....

Comment: Are you familiar with the keyword `this`?

Comment: Are you sure that you want x to be passed by value (meaning a copy of your object will be made) in `void g(x aux)`?

Comment: **this** keyword can help you. **this** keyword point to current object or in another word it reference to itself.

Comment: I tried using this with no success @songyuanyao

Comment: @DenisLeonte Are you sure you wrote `*this` and not `this`? https://godbolt.org/z/eT41h14zj

Comment: yes, I just compiled with ```*this```, still with no success @AndyG

Comment: It could be my compiler, I am using Visual Studio 2019, just updated

Comment: @DenisLeonte: Visual Studio doesn't seem to like that you have a class with a member that shares the same name as the class. Rename `x.x` to something else: https://godbolt.org/z/8b3PfhaE4

Comment: I just solved it, i had to rename the variable x inside the class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have successfully compile? Your member of class was named as class - X.